Why is my build.gradle looking like this? [alias(libs.plugins.com.android.application) apply false]
Why is my build.gradle looking like this?

and not like this:

I was trying to connect Chaquopy with Android Studio.

Please [edit] your question and replace the screenshots with text so that it can be searched and copied.

You use a version catalog with your gradle setup. To learn more about what that is and how to migrate your old gradle files: https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs
Version catalogs are the recommended way of defining gradle dependencies now.

please explain in detail on what i actually have to do... am not able to understand anything from the link you provided (im just 14) i do coding and stuff for a hobby so dont know much

The question was about an explanation on what that is in your gradle file which I answered. If you decide to migrate to version catalogs and want to know what to do then I suggest you read the link in my answer. If you still have problems you can ask a new question. But please be specifc and explain what you have tried so far, questions like "Please do this for me" are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Gradle has multiple ways of doing the same thing, and with new versions come new ways of doing something, and often the new ways are recommended over the old ways. This, unfortunately, can get very confusing.
Your first image shows a Gradle file which uses a multi-project build and a version catalog.
The file is in the top-level directory, and the apply false tells it not to apply these plugins to the top level, but to make them available to sub-projects. Your screenshot shows that you have a sub-project in the app directory.
The version catalog is kept in the file gradle/libs.versions.toml and all projects can then refer to the same version of each library. When adding a new dependency, you should add it to the version catalog first, and then reference it in your project. The file already has a few dependencies during creation time, which will guide you to the correct syntax to use.

Newer versions of Android Studio generate projects that use the version catalog feature. But there's no need to add the Chaquopy plugin via the catalog (unless you want to) – you can still use the exact syntax from the documentation.
For example, this is perfectly fine:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    id("com.chaquo.python") version "15.0.1" apply false
}

